How to automatically send whatsapp reminders 7 days before date column in google sheets?
I have a google sheet which contains a commodity & the fulfilment date. I need a way that I can receive an automated reminder at least 7 days prior to the fulfilment date, so that I can minimise delay/shortage.
This is a snippet of the spreadsheet:

Currently I have this code which is able to send whatsapp messages using Twilio sandbox number, when I manually run it:
// A Message Sender

const { google } = require('googleapis');

// configure a JWT auth client
const privatekey = require("./privatekey.json");

const authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']);

// authentication
authClient.authorize()
    .then(function (tokens) {
        // console.log(tokens);
        console.log("Authentication successfull.\n");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw (error);
    });


// things we shouldn’t share with our code
const secrets = require("./secrets.json");

const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    // ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from
    // A1 notation of the values to retrieve  
    // authorized client  
    spreadsheetId: secrets.spreadsheet_id,
    range: 'Sheet1!A2:E',
    auth: authClient
})
    .then(function (response) {
const rows = response.data.values || [];
if (rows.length) {
        sendMessage(rows);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

const accountSid = secrets.account_sid;
const authToken = secrets.auth_token;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const sandboxNumber = secrets.sandbox_number;

function sendMessage(rows) {

   // stop condition
   if (!rows.length) {
        console.log("---------------------------------");
        return;
    }

   // take information from the first row
    const firstRow = rows.shift();
    const fulfilment_date = firstRow[0];
    const commodity = firstRow[1];
    const quantity = firstRow[2];
    const recipient = firstRow[3];
    const phone_number = firstRow[4];

   // send the message
    client.messages
        .create({
            from: 'whatsapp:' + sandboxNumber,
            to: 'whatsapp:' + phone_number,
            body: `TEST: Next fulfilment is coming up on ${fulfilment_date}\nfor ${commodity} - ${quantity} .` +
                ` A message for ${recipient}`
        })
        .then(function (message) {
            console.log(message.sid + '\n');
            sendMessage(rows);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

}

Can someone please help me out with automating this in a way that I can receive the reminders 7 days before fulfilment date?
Reference:
https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/send-whatsapp-messages-from-google-sheets-javascript-node-js#:~:text=on%20the%20console.-,Configuring%20Twilio%20for%20WhatsApp%20Messages,need%20them%20for%20sending%20messages.
I wrote the code with the help of this article.

Is there any error message on the console ? Any status code on the console ?

There are no error messages. It says “authentication successful” and I have even received the message on my WhatsApp number from Twilio sandbox number. But no luck when I try to put a reminder date function and run the code. Even then it says authentication successful but sends no message.

Can you confirm you are still in the 24-hour window when the code runs?

I don’t know about this, but I had joined the sandbox using “join wait-several” at the time of testing

If there is a paid service by Twilio to send customised reminder messages to WhatsApp, I am happy to subscribe to the same

Can you check your message logs in the console and check if you see the attempted delivery of the messages there?

Yes I do get an alphanumeric code in my console when running

Can you look up that message ID (alphanumeric code) in the logs of your program and see if it's associated to an error message in the message log I linked above?

I am receiving messages, there is no error message. The problem is that I do not know how to automate this, so that every time a new record is added, I can receive the message on WhatsApp 7 days prior to the fulfilment date
